# Raspberry Pi Libc corrupted

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, libc

My Raspberry Pi will not install anything anymore, as it keeps on complaining about a half-installed libc6. For example, when I try to install g++ 4.7:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/workspace $ sudo apt-get install g++-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.7 : Depends: libstdc++6-4.7-dev (= 4.7.2-5+rpi1) but it is not going to be installed
 libkrb5-3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u3 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: glibc-2.19-1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, then I run `sudo apt-get install -f`, and it gives me this error:

```
dpkg: error processing libc6:armhf (--configure):
 package libc6:armhf is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added wrong repository to your /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*,
look at

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

there should be no debian repos in sources lists, also check the raspbian version, looks like you're on "wheezy", so remove "sid" or "jessie", when you fix it, do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If your sources.list was correct, your should learn not to install debs from random sites.

Now to fix your libc6, reinstall it

```
wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.13-38%2brpi2%2bdeb7u3_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libc6-dev_2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u3_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it's to difficult for you to fix sources.list or that didn't help, please provide the output of the following commands

```
apt-cache policy libc6
apt-cache policy libc6-dev
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me, from the 2015 image

```
wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.13-38%2brpi2%2bdeb7u3_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libc6-dev_2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u3_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```